# Broke vs broken - which is correct in the below sentence?

Tags: grammar

I dropped my iPad and broken/broke it. It seems like one of those days.

Answer (score 1):

> Yesterday, I dropped my iPad and broke it. = *past simple, describes a past event*

> I have dropped my iPad and (have) broken it. = *present perfect, stresses the importance of an event which happened at an indefinite time in the past - You don't have a working phone now. When did you break it? Not important.*

Comment: Also, *I broke my iPad, so what I now have doesn't work - it's **a broken iPad***.